Testing CustomErroHandler with AuthGuard fails to popup 'you encountered a bug' and fails redirect to 500 page
Is there a different global handler chokepoint for guards and resolvers.  I tried the following code and it did not popup my 'you encountered a bug' dialogue.  Any html onclick that receives an exception pops up the dialog thanks to our installation of global error handler.
I tried this to simulate a bug
export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn | CanActivateChildFn = (route, state) => {
    const router: Router = inject(Router);
    const authSvc = inject(AuthService);
    const response = authSvc.check();
    const observable = from(response);

    if(true)
        throw new Error("testing bugs");
};

I tried this as well as this should do the same
export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn | CanActivateChildFn = (route, state) => {
    const router: Router = inject(Router);
    const authSvc = inject(AuthService);
    const response = authSvc.check();
    const observable = from(response);

    // Check the authentication status
    return observable
        .pipe(
            switchMap((authenticated) => {
                    if(true)
                        throw new Error("testing bugs");
            })
        );
};

Now it gets more interesting.   The following code WORKS when I click the tab and 'you encountered a bug pops up', BUT if I bookmark the url and go straight there to url, it fails like the above code
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        if(true)
            throw new Error("simulat bug");

        const promise = this._userService.fetch().then((res) => { return null; });
        return from(promise); //convert promise to observable
    }

Same result in this case as well
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        const promise = this._userService.fetch().then((res) => { return null; });
        const observable = from(promise); //convert promise to observable

        return observable
            .pipe(
                switchMap(() => {
                    throw new Error("fail please to simulate bug")
                })
            );
    }

Is there a different ROUTER global handler I can install to just redirect to a plain html page to render 500 or something instead of leaving the user stuck with a spinner?
I tried all of the above stuff seeing if CustomerErrorHandler would run but it does not.
